# Evaluating $( 1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x^{2}}$ as $x \to -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I think I have to use the fact that  $( 1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x^2}$ tends to $e$ as $x$ tends to minus infinity. But I'm not sure how to apply it . . . Maybe I can compare it to something; like, if it's smaller than something that tends to $0$ then will it tend to zero?

Thanks.

Comment: $( 1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x^{2}} = e^{x ln(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}}$This is what I have tried to use definition of $e$. I wasnt sure if it's valid to say that some parts of the power goes to 1 and some goes to minus infinity. Hence power goes to minus infinity. And the whole thing is 0. Is this valid?

Comment: You can indeed write this (mind the parenthesis):
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2} = e^{x\ln\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]}$$
To prove the whole thing goes to $0$, you only need to prove that the exponent $x\ln\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]$ goes to $-\infty$. You can argue this, since you have to factors, one ($x$) going to $-\infty$, and the other converging to $\ln e=1$ -- since in this case $\lim fg = \lim f \cdot\lim g$, and $\lim g=\lim \ln h$ with $h\to e$ and $\ln$ continuous (composition of limit).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I can think of: write
\begin{align*}
\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2} &= e^{x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} \\
&= e^{x^2\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)} \\
&=e^{x-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)}
\xrightarrow[x\to-\infty]{} 0
\end{align*}
where we use the fact that $\ln(1+\varepsilon)=\varepsilon-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2}+o(\varepsilon^2)$ where $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please check my comment above? Is it valid?

Comment: Yes (albeit a bit contrived, since the limit $e$ you're using is most of the time proven using the technique above).

Comment: Clément: Actually it seems that in the US they *define* $\mathrm e$ as the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$. Which is why you shall see quite a few détours by this "basic fact" in MSE posts. I know, this is weird. Another example is the use and abuse of L'Hôpital's rule, considered as a cornerstone of Analysis... :-)

Comment: Hmmm... peculiar. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

$$x\leqslant-1\implies0\leqslant1+\frac1x\leqslant\mathrm e^{1/x}\implies\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x^2}\leqslant\mathrm e^x$$